# Package Acronym - margin problem with long abbreviations in glossary

Tags: spacing, glossaries

Is there a way to increase the margin between abbreviation and explanation in the `acronym` glossary?

I've got some long abbreviations that are bigger than the standard margin and mess up the layout. (Like "XML-RPC", for example.)

I only found `\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}`, but that belongs sadly to `nomencl`. Is there something similar for `acronym`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 3 of the package documentation:

> For example, if *HBCI* is the longest acronym used, the list should start with
>   `\begin{acronym}[HBCI]`

Comment: Damn to slow ;-)

Comment: omg, thank you both! didn't expect it to be so easy... :)

Answer (score 5):

You used the environment `acronym` which has an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\acresetall
\section{Intro}
as \acs{CDMA} \qquad\acf{CDMA}

\acs{test} \qquad\acf{test}

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[Text with the largest label]
 \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
 \acro{test}{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
             Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text }
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```